# PHPUnit 5.6: setExpectedException InvalidArgumentException

Tags: php, phpunit

I have this code in PHP:

```
public function customersMethod()
{
    //...

    if (0 == count($customers)) {
        throw new \InvalidArgumentException("Le tage n'existe pas", 400);
    }
}
```

I mock it by this code:

```
   /**
     * @covers \Models\Customers::customersMethod()
     */
    public function customersMethodTest()
    {
        //...

        if(count($tag) == 0){
            $this->setExpectedException('\InvalidArgumentException', 'Le tage n\'existe pas');
        }
    }
```

It display an error message:

> Failed asserting that exception of type "\InvalidArgumentException" is
>   thrown.

I don't know where the error in my code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of the below variants will work:

```php
$this->setExpectedException('InvalidArgumentException', 'Le tage n\'existe pas');

$this->setExpectedException(\InvalidArgumentException::class, 'Le tage n\'existe pas');
```

Note that this is a call that's usually made at the beginning of your test. Also, a condition in your test case looks weird. Tests shouldn't be conditional.